# Keep getting" Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for picturebox array

Tags: c#

```
private void radar_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        x[i] = Readi(0x5C850C + (0x5A4 * i));
        y[i] = Readi(0x5C8510 + (0x5A4 * i));
        players[i].Location = new Point(x[i], y[i]);
    }
}
```

and yeah, before that:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int []x=new int[32];int []y=new int[32];
    PictureBox[] players=new PictureBox[32];    
    ...  
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is PictureBox)
            {
                var myPicturebBox = (PictureBox)ctrl;
                players[i] = myPicturebBox;
                this.Controls.Add(players[i]);
                i++;

            }
        }
        radar.Interval = 100;
        radar.Start();
    }
```

What I keep getting is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I don't want to make new object on every timer tick, I just want to change i-th picturebox's location. Any ideas?
Nulls are not x and y,null is pictebox array.(I tried adding `players[i]=new PictureBox();` and it worked.That's how I know)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: is players null in radar_Tick?

Comment: What is those two x[i] and y[i], did you create two arrays **x** and **y** and initialized them?

Comment: I guess,everything I did in radar_tick is shown in the code.What should I do if it's null?
@DWright

Comment: Well, first is it null?  Or per @Lourayad, is `x` or `y` null. First thing to do is to figure out what is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have 32 `PictureBox` objects and you want to change their Locations, you need to make each of the `players` array members reference a `PictureBox`.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is PictureBox)
    {
        var myPicturebBox = (PictureBox)ctrl;
        players[i] = myPictureBox;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Now your array members reference all of the `PictureBox` objects in your `Form`.

**Edit**

Since your PictureBox objects are all created programmatically, you **have** to instatiate them before you can use them, like this:

```
PictureBox myPictureBox = new PictureBox();
```

Now you need to add the PictureBox to the `Controls` collection of the `Form`:

```
this.Controls.Add(myPictureBox)
```

Then you can use the previous code, do this for all of the PictureBoxes using a loop.

Comment: This into radar_Tick?I've tried this,but it always creates another picturebox,and as I mentioned,I don't want new picturebox,I just want to change it's location.

Comment: Then you need to fill your `players` array with the `PictureBox` objects that already exist.

Comment: Does it mean I have to add 32 pictureBoxes on my Form?Isn't there any easier way?Huh

Comment: No, not in `radar_Tick`, put it in `Form_Load` or somewhere similar.

Comment: You added the PictureBoxes from the designer ? or were they created programmatically ?

Comment: Then you probably didn't instatiate them with the `new` keyword, did you? And you need to add them to the `Form`'s `Controls ` collection.

Comment: Didn't see u have edited.It worked by the way,thank u so much.